# How to Increase limit of Analytics Query Result in Azure Analytics Applicationinsights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I have run a query on https://analytics.applicationinsights.io like the following:

```
traces
| where timestamp >= datetime(2017-03-17T13:12:59.999Z) and timestamp < 
  datetime(2017-03-21T12:13:12.001Z)
| where (itemType == 'trace' and (timestamp >= datetime(2017-03-
  17T13:13:00.000Z) and timestamp <= datetime(2017-04-23T12:13:12.000Z)))
```

But 10000 of 400000 existed records were reflected (see in the following).

[image]

The question is "How to increase this limit?".

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is possible using the portal experience, but I have done it in the past using the preview APIs as they support $skip and $top.

You can read about the API here:
https://dev.applicationinsights.io/reference/get-events

What I did was to iterate over all requests in a Power BI report and then do my data visualization in Power BI.